# How to do a URL redirect to the latest content?

Tags: redirection

This should be pretty simple, but what would be the best way to set up a 301 redirect to the latest post of a node type, for example.

For example: `example.com/blog/latest` -> `example.com/node/*`

Ehat I was originally was doing was using views, getting the path of the latest post (+ random, also in views) and rewrite the results with a simple `<a href="[path]">Latest</a>`.

But, since I need to include this in email message, a URL is desired (as well as adding Google Analytics UTM Parameters).

What would be the simplest, site builder way to do this?

Comment: You probably don't want a 301 redirect (Moved Permanently) since you don't intend to permanently associate /blog/latest with a given node. Alternatively, display the latest blog post at /blog/latest using a view or the "Smart Node Links" module recommended by 2pha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a module for that.
[Smart Node Links](https://www.drupal.org/project/smartnodelinks)

Comment: Brilliant, exactly solves my use case.